# "Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined or null reference" after commenting out div

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm getting the error "Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined or null reference" in my website since I commented out 2 divs in a bootstrap carousel. This carousel was developed by someone else who is unavailable to me. I don't see how commenting out a div would cause this error. It does not occur when the divs are left in.

```
<!-- Carousel -->
<div id="homepage-slider">
  <div id="feature-wrap">
      <div class="iosSlider">
          <div     class="slider">                                                              
            {2}                
            <div class="item" id="2">
                <a href="{0}/{1}/products/test1"><img     src="{0}/Content/images/home/index/myPic.jpg" style="width: 100%;" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="3">
                <a href="{0}/{1}/products/test2"><img src="{0}/Content/images/home/index/myPic2.jpg" style="width: 100%;" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="4">                    
                <a href="https://myPage.myCompany.com/"     target="_blank"><img src="{0}/Content/images/home/index/myPic3.jpg"     style="width: 100%;" /></a>
            </div>  <!-- Commenting out this div         -->                          
          </div>
          <div class="iosSliderButtons">                
              {3}  
              <div class="button"></div>
              <div class="button"></div>
              <div class="button"></div> <!-- Commenting out this div -->
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="nextSlide"></div>
      <div id="previousSlide"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This HTML is called from another file, called Index.cshtml like so:

```
 <div id="view-home">
 @Html.Raw(Resources.HtmlContent.HomePageContent.FormatWith(host, 

 currentWebAlias, myHTML1, myHTML2))
 </div>
```

myHTML1 & myHTML2 are set earlier in the file, and this HTML is then used to populate the placeholders (marked {2} and {3}) in the page above.

I'm also getting a similar error, except it refers to 'unobtrusive'.
This all works fine when the divs are not commented out, but I don't see how removing a div would cause these errors to occur all of a sudden.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out a div can cause an error since that element is referenced in carrousel plugin. To be precise since javascript cannot find that element which is now undefined, accessing elements property of undefined causes this error.

Whoever wrote this plugin did not have in mind for you to play around with its structure, since he made it error prone.

This property is most likely used in calculation for carrousel plugin slide effects, you can check more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth

Comment: Thanks for your response. When you say plugin, what do you mean - the javascript library? I can't change that as it is just an imported library. I have searched for any hard-coded references to a certain number of slides in the carousel, but I can't find anything. One of the divs I have commented out (the button one) does not have an id, so I can't find where it is being referenced. I suppose I could look for any references to the div with id="4", although that would mean searching for "4" in my solution, and there are bound to be lots of those!

Comment: Yes I mean javascript library. I doubt that it has hardcoded values like that, if you are not very skilled in reading other people's code it would be hard for you to notice why something breaks. Can you give a link to that library?

Comment: Thanks. I've just got the error re the unobtrusive property. When I debug it using VS 2015, I can see that it's coming from the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js library, and it's 'dynamic' - so I presume it's generated on the fly? So I don't know how I can provide the code for that library. I suppose, it looks like something, somewhere is referencing the div I've commented out, but I can't find what/where it is!

Comment: Something is surely referencing this element, hence the error. For this unobtrusive error... do you properly load your jquery validate library before you load jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js?

Comment: Sometimes, I get an error re 'popover'. Same thing - can't get popover for null or undefined reference. Here's the code where popover is used:

Comment: // Auto-create popovers for all links configured to be popovers
            $(document).popover({
              selector: 'a[data-toggle="popover"]',
              html: true,
              placement: 'top'
          });

Comment: I cannot debug all of your code :) if something is undefined you are missing it surely, meybe you did not include your files correctly (in correct order). Open another question on different topic, and if this answer helped you marked it as read. For different problems also provide full code and errors.

Comment: I haven't changed how any of the libraries are loaded, as all I needed to do was remove this div to remove one of the slides on the carousel. I can see that the following files are referenced in the _MasterLayout.cshtml file, in this order:

Comment: 'jquery-validate': 'vendor/jquery.validate.min',
                'jquery-validate-unobtrusive': 'vendor/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min',
                'jquery-unobtrusive-custom': 'vendor/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.custom',
                'jquery-unobtrusive-ajax': 'vendor/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax',

Comment: Thanks for your help.